# D3.js setup node text font-size base on how many node text there

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I do have one parent node, it has 10 children, in the further, it may have 50 or more...
So I want the text node font size to change to smaller dynamically according to the node length.

```js
  XXX.append('text')
        .attr('x', d => d.x)
        .attr('y', d => d.y)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('font-size', "1em");
```

Currently all 1em, so when more nodes, it looks not good...

Comment: To be able to help you, it is needed more context on the code snippet. What is XXX? And please be more explicit on what you have working, and what you want to achieve. For example, it's not clear if you want to attach the text to the parent or to every children, and what do you mean with "node length"?

Comment: Please provide a working snippet or a link to fiddle / codepen

Comment: @JerónimoEkerd  I have https://vizhub.com/BoykaZhu/1ab46394dfe64b819a15bcdb8cacb270?edit=files&file=index.js

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I have https://vizhub.com/BoykaZhu/1ab46394dfe64b819a15bcdb8cacb270?edit=files&file=index.js
Kindly help to review

Comment: @BoykaZhu your link seems to be broken

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky kindly try it again? https://vizhub.com/BoykaZhu/1ab46394dfe64b819a15bcdb8cacb270?edit=files&file=index.js

Comment: @BoykaZhu you can use `getBBox` to retrieve the actual text width and then reduce the font size until it fits

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky, thanks. I made updates but did not use getBBox,  looks like getBBox could get text content width, not the target I want.  My updates in https://vizhub.com/BoykaZhu/1ab46394dfe64b819a15bcdb8cacb270?edit=files&file=index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (see it working in a [viz](https://vizhub.com/mrovinsky/8b9bb67f2fcf42fda7188c24a8064845?edit=files&file=index.js)):

```
const items = root.descendants();
    const delta = Math.abs(items[1].x - items[2].x) - 8;
    console.log({delta});
  
    g.selectAll('text').data(items)
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr("transform", (d) => "translate("+ (d.x) +","+ (d.y) +")")
      .append('text')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text(d => d.data.name)
      .each(function(d) {
        const text = select(this);
        let fontSize = 0;
        let width = 0;
        while(width < delta) {
          fontSize++;
          text.attr('font-size', fontSize);
          width = text.node().getBBox().width;
        }
      });
```